# How to get all records from GAE datastore with particular parent?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have several records in my database with the same parent. How can I get all of them by parent?

Comment: Looks like I'll have to create separate property and keep there key_name value of the parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, looks like the following code works:

```
items = ITEM.gql('WHERE ANCESTOR IS :parent', parent=parent_key).fetch(5)
```