# Filtering datastore results by parent entity

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, go

This question as already been answered for Python: 
[How to get all records from GAE datastore with particular parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868333/how-to-get-all-records-from-gae-datastore-with-particular-parent)

How do I do it in Go? I would like to do something like:

```
t := new(TagRecord)
k, err := datastore.DecodeKey(r.URL.Path[1:])
...
_, err = datastore.NewQuery("TagRecord").
  Filter("Parent =", k). 
  Order("-CreatedAt").
  Limit(1).
  Run(c).Next(t)
```

...but this fails miserably with the following error:

```
datastore: query has no more results
```

When I try filtering by other properties, including those hard coded into the filter and those passed through the URL, the query runs properly and populates t with the proper properties. With what humiliating simplicity can my problem be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's tripping you up here is that querying by parent does not use Filter(). Instead, you use an [ancestor constraint](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#Query.Ancestor):

```
q := datastore.NewQuery("TagRecord").
    Ancestor(k).
    Order("-CreatedAt").
    Limit(1)

// etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you also define the index for this specific query and upload the index config file